# creating a user on container and host with same linux user id

Tags: linux, containers

I have an image which is created from ubuntu 22 and I install a particular package using apt, `apt install`  also does creation of a user specific to that package say user1 in the image. While, the container starts up, the user1 has a different user id than what is there as user1's id in my host.

I thought maybe I will create user1 with a specific id in both the host and container. With this, while doing `apt install` it gave me an exception saying `adduser: The user user1 already exists, but is not a system user. Exiting.`. So, I think it has to be system user.

Just wanted to know if there is a right way to make sure the user id is same on the host and the container.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do nothing.

The container runs in an isolated environment.  In principle the numeric user IDs are the same numbers in the host and container environments, but under normal circumstances the host and container can't access each other's files, so it doesn't matter.

In Kubernetes this is doubly true.  Since you'll normally have multiple nodes, and a key design point of Kubernetes is that nodes can be easily replaced, what's running on the host system (and which host system it is) doesn't really matter.

Comment: So what?  Why does it matter?  Just so long as everything is self-consistent within the container, it shouldn't be affected by the host's `/etc/passwd` file (which it can't see).